# How to set a variable back to zero after a certain period of time

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to work on a Ping Pong game as a learning activity for Unity. I'm working on making a reset system for the ping pong ball if it gets stuck bouncing up and down for eternity.

I set up a bottom wall collider trigger and a top wall collider trigger to increment a contact variable by 1. For example, if the ball hits the top wall of the game the `HitsTop` variable will increment by 1.

Likewise for the bottom wall. My issue is, when the ball hits the bottom wall and top wall ten times it resets the ball position.

I want to add code that will reset the `HitsTop` and the `HitsBottom` variables after a certain period of time, say, 5 seconds.

Is this possible in C#?

My code is as such:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int PlayerScore1 = 0;
    public static int PlayerScore2 = 0;
    public static int HitsTop = 0;
    public static int HitsBottom = 0;

    public GUISkin layout;

    Transform theBall;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        theBall = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Ball").transform;
    }

    public static void Score (string wallID) {
        if (wallID == "rightWall")
        {
            PlayerScore1++;
        } else if (wallID == "leftWall") {
            PlayerScore2++;
        }

        if (wallID == "topWallTrigger")
        {
            HitsTop++;
        } else if (wallID == "bottomWallTrigger") {
            HitsBottom++;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI () {
        GUI.skin = layout;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 150 - 12, 20, 100, 100), "" + PlayerScore1 + HitsTop);
        GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 + 150 + 12, 20, 100, 100), "" + PlayerScore2 + HitsBottom);

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 60, 35, 120, 53), "RESTART"))
        {
            PlayerScore1 = 0;
            PlayerScore2 = 0;
            HitsTop = 0;
            HitsBottom = 0;
            theBall.gameObject.SendMessage("RestartGame", 0.5f, SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver);
        }

        if (PlayerScore1 == 10)
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 150, 200, 2000, 1000), "PLAYER ONE WINS");
            theBall.gameObject.SendMessage("ResetBall", null, SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver);
        } else if (PlayerScore2 == 10)
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 150, 200, 2000, 1000), "PLAYER TWO WINS");
            theBall.gameObject.SendMessage("ResetBall", null, SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver);
        }
        if (HitsTop == 10) {
            theBall.gameObject.SendMessage("RestartGame", 1.0f, SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver);
            HitsTop = 0;
        } else if (HitsBottom == 10) {
            theBall.gameObject.SendMessage("RestartGame", 1.0f, SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver);
            HitsBottom = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible in C# -- please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Time.deltaTime` to decrement a variable.

```
float timer = 5;    

void Update()
{
  //This will decrement the timer's value by the time. Once this hits zero, the timer is reset to its original value.
  timer -= Time.deltaTime;
  if(timer <= 0)
  {
   //Call reset game function
    timer = 5;
  }
}
```

Also when you increment `HitsTop` or `HitsBottom`, reset the timer to 5.

Comment: This code worked beautifully for me. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad to be of service